# Помогите решить проблему с merge ветки

Tags: git

У меня есть ветка которую надо влить в мою основную я пишу:

```
git merge feature/86963.create604For251&252
merge: feature/86963.create604For251 - not something we can merge
'252' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Это наверно из за неудачного названия с цифрой на конце. Помогите пожалуйста выкрутится.

Comment: а кавычками можно ограничить от feature и до конца?

Comment: Не только можно, но, скорее всего, **нужно**.

Comment: @D-side к стыду моему, ни разу в консоли не писал гитовские команды - всё за меня делает мой несчастный раб - IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git merge feature/86963.create604For251&252
                                       ^----- это разделитель команд
```

Амперсанд надо экранировать. В засивимости от ОС могут быть разные способы, но полагаю, что везде сработает помещение имени ветки в кавычки:

```
git merge "feature/86963.create604For251&252"
```